# reverse iteration of map in c++ missing out the first element

Tags: c++

I have a code where I am reverse iterating a map in C++. For n pairs in map, sometimes the map prints out n pairs, sometimes n-1 pairs.
for test case

```
4 2    
2 1  
3 5  
2 3  
1 5
```

it prints 4 hi's, for the next case 3 hi's

```
4 1  
0 2  
0 3  
3 5  
0 6
```

My code:

```
include cmath, cstdio, vector, iostream, map, algorithm, using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n,f;
    cin >> n >> f;
    int k[n],l[n],dif[n];
    map<int,int> m;
    map<int,int>::reverse_iterator it;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d %d\n",&k[i],&l[i]);
        dif[i] = l[i]-k[i];
        m.insert(make_pair(dif[i],l[i]));
    }

    int a = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for(it = m.rbegin(); it != m.rend(); ++it ) {
        cout << "hi" << endl;
        int article = it->second - it->first;
        int people = it->second;

        if (a < f and article!=0){
            a++;

            if (2*article > people){
                sum = sum + people;
            } else {
                sum = sum + (2*article);
            }
        } else {

            if (article > people){
                sum = sum + people;
            } else {
                sum = sum + article;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want a `multimap` instead of a `map`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with reverse iteration, it would be the same with forward iteration. A map has a pair of a key and a value. Each key can only be included in the map once. When you insert the same key again the previous value is overwritten. In your second test case you are setting the key `0` three times:

```
4 1
0 2 <--
0 3 <--
3 5
0 6 <--
```

So your map actually only has three values, so the three "Hi" are correct. In your first example you overwrite key `2` only twice, so the four "Hi". Maybe a map is not the correct container you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't see that.